# Validating multiple text boxes in single JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

> i have 7 textbox and i want to validate as Required field OnClientClick
>   click of a button named as Update
>   so is there any way i could do it using Javascript
>   i have tried this code but it's not working as one of them 
>   ps: i am new to JS

```
   function fnCheck(val) {
            var v = val.id.split('_')[1];
            var merter = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txtMeterIdn').value.trim();
            var Billper = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txBillPer').value.trim()
            var Endkwh = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txEndKwh').value.trim();
            var startkwh = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txStartKwh').value.trim();
            var ReadEndDate = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txReadEndDate').value.trim();
            var ReadStartDate = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txReadStartDate').value.trim();
            var CTFACT = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txCTFact').value.trim();
            if (merter != '') {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("Meter Identifier is Required Field");
            return false;
        }

        if (Billper != '') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Bill Period is Required Field");
            return false;
        }

        if (Endkwh != '') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("EndKwh is Required Field");
            return false;
        }
        if (startkwh != '') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("StartKwh is Required Field");
            return false;
        }
        if (ReadEndDate != '') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Read EndDate is Required Field");
            return false;
        }

        if (ReadStartDate != '') {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert("Read StartDate is Required Field");
            return false;
        }
        if (CTFACT != '') {
            return true;
        }
        else
        { alert("CT Factor is Required Field");
        return false;
        }
        }
 <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" Style="background-color: #B2DE94; width: 40px"  CausesValidation="false" runat="server"  OnClientClick="fnCheck(this);" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
```

Comment: Why don't you use [RequiredFieldValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78xxk8k.aspx)?

Comment: have tried it but it's not working for some weird reason in editable gridview

Comment: @KarthickRaju aren't there way to validate BY JS ?

Comment: @KarthickRaju Solved it using JS kindly review it

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ValidationGroup="gridview" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="gridview" CausesValidation="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code has been taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248527/javascript-validation-to-textbox-in-a-gridview-in-asp-net)

I have verified with sample project and works for your scenario

Comment: What do you mean JS solution? If you use GridView then it's asp.net, right? If so you can achieve the same with just RequiredFieldValidator. JS code not required for this scenario. Like I said, I tried the code and it's throwing error message set for the field

Comment: if Required validator was working i would not have ben using JS

Comment: Sounds like a [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Try fixing the original problem: The Validator Control not working.

Comment: Yes VDWWD. I don't know how it's not working for Deepak Jain. I have posted 2 working codes with screenshot. Hope, issue would have been resolved for him

Comment: actually i have made  CausesValidation="false" as my rowupdating event was faling because of it @KarthickRaju

Answer (score 0):

Deepak,

Below is my Gridview code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="DataKeyId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="gridview" CausesValidation="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="gridview" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup="gridview" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ValidationGroup="gridview" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ValidationGroup="gridview" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>                    
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

By clicking on button avail inside the GridView, below attachment error appears

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is the another set of version to throw error message at row level

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="YourDataKey" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup = '<%# "Group_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' CausesValidation="true" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup = '<%# "Group_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'  ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup = '<%# "Group_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'  ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ValidationGroup = '<%# "Group_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ValidationGroup = '<%# "Group_" + Container.DataItemIndex %>' ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>                    
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Third row button is clicked in the below attachment and second column has value. So, error appears for the rest of the controls of the row

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> > ok i have worked on my JS function and it worked for me.hope it will
> >     work for everyone else.in my code i have taken a variable
>
> `success` which is working as a flag and i am checking it twice and
>   returning `true` at the end so that if one of the textbox is not empty
>   and other not it will not return true.
>   **sorry for poor editing**

```
 function fnCheck(val) {
        var success = true;
        var v = val.id.split('_')[1];
        var merter = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txtMeterIdn').value.trim();
        var Billper = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txBillPer').value.trim()
        var Endkwh = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txEndKwh').value.trim();
        var startkwh = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txStartKwh').value.trim();
        var ReadEndDate = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txReadEndDate').value.trim();
        var ReadStartDate = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txReadStartDate').value.trim();
        var CTFACT = document.getElementById('GridSubMeter_' + v + '_txCTFact').value.trim();
        debugger;
        if (merter != '') {

        }
        else {
            alert("Meter Identifier is Required Field");
            success = false;
    }

    if (Billper != '') {

    }
    else {
        alert("Bill Period is Required Field");
        success = false;
    }

    if (Endkwh != '') {

    }
    else {
        alert("EndKwh is Required Field");
        success = false;
    }
    if (startkwh != '') {

    }
    else {
        alert("StartKwh is Required Field");
        success = false;
    }
    if (ReadEndDate != '') {

    }
    else {
        alert("Read EndDate is Required Field");
        success = false;
    }

    if (ReadStartDate != '') {

    }
    else {
        alert("Read StartDate is Required Field");
        success = false;
    }
    if (CTFACT != '') {

    }
    else
    { alert("CT Factor is Required Field");
    success = false;
}

return success;

    }
```

**onclientclick**

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Update" Style="background-color: #B2DE94; width: 40px"  CausesValidation="false" runat="server"  OnClientClick="return fnCheck(this);" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
```